BackDropFilter blur is not applying to Image
I wanted to blur my image, I tried this:
BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.blur(
    sigmaX: 10,
    sigmaY: 10
  ),
  child: Image.file(
    File(imagePath),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  )
)

but my problem is that is not applying to the image and I am honestly no idea why?

use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageFiltered-class.html instead, the docs say: "Applies an ImageFilter to its child. An image filter will always apply its filter operation to the child widget, even if said filter is conceptually a "no-op", such as an ImageFilter.blur with a radius of 0 or an ImageFilter.matrix with an identity matrix."

Use ImageFiltered. It's more performant.
ImageFiltered(
      imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
        sigmaX: 10,
        sigmaY: 10,
        tileMode: TileMode.decal,
      ),
      child: Image(image: _imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
    );

BackdropFilter created for "Frosted Glass" effect to blur background.
Also, BackdropFilter blurs everything behind your widget and ImageFiltered affects only it's child.

BackdropFilter applies a blur only to the content behind it, not the child widget itself. In your case, since the Image.file is the direct child, the blur won't be applied to the image as you expected. I've used a network image to show an example that is easy to apply.
Stack(
      children: [
        Image.network(
          'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black
                    .withOpacity(0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),

